# What's a good structure for storing data during traversing of a parse tree? It's for a language server protocol implementation

Tags: python, antlr4, language-server-protocol

I'm implementing the language server protocol for a C++ testing framework, using Python3. I use ANTLR4 to parse the text file, and I have a working parser and I use the Listener pattern to traverse the results.

But what's the best way to store the data to easily query the structure? In The features I'm looking to implement typically the input to the server is a file name and line number, and the return value is another file and line. I.e something like go-to definition.

For each given rule I understand I have to save the relevant date. For example in an Listener function like `enterFunctionDefition()` I could save the function name, context, line number. I imagine this could be saved a simple JSON or XML tree or even an AST (abstract syntax tree). And then search that structure for items containing the desired filename and line number.

There has to be some kind of example out there how to do this, right? I've been googling alot but I just can't seem to find the instructions, but I might be misunderstanding some concept.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let's be clear: the LSP server is a process that listens for LSP queries and sends back responses. There is no need for persistence of any data structures as JSON or XML. Your server will need to look over the parse tree and find defining and applied occurrences of an identifier across all files. Therefore you will need to create a symbol table for all files.

Comment: Ok, fair point, maybe my wording is poor. I could rephrase it to "what

Comment: I'm starting to realize I might have misunderstood how to use the parse tree. I thought I should traverse all files of interest once, and build a some kind of AST during the process, and then later query that AST. That's wrong, or? Am I supposed to traverse the parse tree each time I'm looking for a symbol? Btw, what do you mean by symbol table?